# Blank page rendered in Playwright headless test

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci, playwright

I am writing an end-to-end test (jest-runner) with Playwright where I spawn my ui, backend and db with Docker Compose. It works well on my local machine but when I ran the same test in the Gitlab, it fails.
After debugging using screenshots, docker container logs and playwright logs I see the following ->

- After the domcontentloaded event is fired, the commit event is not fired.
- The screenshot shows a blank page.
- The correct files were served by the ui container (there is no connectivity problem)

`2023-02-06T17:18:51.101Z pw:api <= page.goto succeeded 2023-02-06T17:18:51.103Z pw:api   "domcontentloaded" event fired 2023-02-06T17:18:51.338Z pw:api   "networkidle" event fired`

Any help is appreciated.

I checked the docker container logs, the playwright logs and screenshots.